# Inserting a Row Only If Non-Consecutively

Tags: mysql

To prevent **me** from entering data consecutively, I make a query on the last user that matches a certain condition. If the last **user** is not **me**, then data can be inserted. Below shows the two queries that are performed:

```
SELECT user FROM Table WHERE condition='condition' ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 1;

if(user != me)
{
 INSERT INTO Table (user, details) VALUES ('me', 'details');
}
```

Would it be better to carry out this check within the `INSERT` statement, and how would the query goes?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this within the INSERT statement so your solution is fine.

Comment: I will accept your answer if you receive 5 ticks from the community here :)